# Convex combinations of Bernoulli Measures

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, symbolic-dynamics

How big is the weak-* closure of the set of all (finite) convex combinations of Bernoulli measures among all invariant probability measures?

I mean, we are in the symbolic space $\{1,2,\ldots,d\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and I would like to know, how big the (weak-*) closure of the set $C$ is, where
$$C = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \eta_i: n \in \mathbb{N}; \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=1; \eta_i = \mathrm{Ber}(p^i_1,\ldots,p^i_d) \right\}.$$

Of course, any reference towards this topic may be useful.

Thanks a lot for your attention

Comment: What is your measure of "bigness"?  [de Finetti's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Finetti's_theorem) states that the convex mixtures of Bernoulli measures are precisely the measures that are invariant under finite permutations of the indices.

Comment: @Algernon "Bigness" in the sense this set can be almost everything or, on the opposite, has so many properties, is so specific that only a few invariant measures can be there...

Comment: This is precisely the set of all measures of the form $\int m\, d\mathbb{P}(m)$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is a Borel probability measure on the set of Bernoulli measures (a closed set). So, it's a closed face of the set of invariant measures.

Comment: @IanMorris, sorry, but $\int m d\mathbb{P}(m)$ is kind of a ergodic decomposition? I mean, a Borel probability on the space of Bernoulli measures... I don't understand how this integral you wrote works...

Comment: I'll expand on this as an answer.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you actually care about invariantness, or where you meant to put it?  You mention it, but then use distinct $p^i_j$ for different $j$ which is not invariant.

Comment: Noah, I'm not sure I understand: doesn't $\eta_i$ satisfy $\eta_i([x_1\cdots x_n])=p^i_{x_1}\cdots p^i_{x_n}$ for each $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?

Comment: Dear @IanMorris, are you sure that the only ergodic measures on that space are Bernoulli measures? It means that if a ergodic measure $\eta$ satisfies: $$\eta = \lim_{n}\sum_{i=1}^{M_{n}}\alpha_{i}^{n}Ber_{i}^{n}$$ so it must be Bernoulli... well, I will try more, but I can't see this even when I suppose $\eta$ mixing... thanks for your attention

Comment: Dear @NoahStein, yes, professor Ian Morris is right, each $i$ refers to a Bernoulli measure $\eta_{i}$

Comment: If an invariant measure is a proper linear combination of two non-identical invariant measures, it is not ergodic. This is Theorem 6.10.iii in Walters' book. Every measure $\eta$ in the closure of $C$ is a proper linear combination of invariant measures unless the associated measure $\mathbb{P}$ is a Dirac measure, in which case $\eta$ is a Bernoulli measure.

Comment: Dear @IanMorris, every measure in $C$ is a proper linear combination of invariant measures, but, in the closure of $C$, for instance the $\eta$ I wrote before: $$\eta = \lim_{n}\sum_{i=1}^{M_{n}}\alpha_{i}^{n}Ber_{i}^{n},$$ you may have $M_{n}\rightarrow \infty$, so, it looks like you can have complicated measures on the closure...

Comment: I don't see anything complicated about this limit. Write each term in the sequence as $\int m\,d\mathbb{P}_n$ where $\mathbb{P}_n=\sum_{i=1}^{M_n} \alpha_i^n \delta_{Ber_i^n}$, then $\eta = \int m\,d\mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the weak-* limit of the measures $m_n$. If $\mathbb{P}$ is a point mass then this is a Bernoulli measure, if not then $\eta$ is not ergodic.

Comment: Sorry, "where $\mathbb{P}$ is the weak-* limit of the measures $\mathbb{P}_n$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of Bernoulli measures $B$ is closed, and the closure of $C$ is precisely the set of measures of the form $\int m\,d\mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is a Borel probability measure on the set of Bernoulli  measures.

Let me unpack that statement a little. Let $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$ denote the set of shift-invariant Borel probability measures on $\Sigma_d:=\{1,\ldots,d\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This we equip with the weak-* topology, which is the smallest topology on $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$ such that for every continuous function $f \colon \Sigma_d \to \mathbb{R}$, the map $m \mapsto \int f\,dm$ is a continuous function from $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

This topology (which is metrisable) defines a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$. A linear combination of measures $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_im_i \in \mathcal{M}_\sigma$ satisfies
$$\int f\,d\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i m_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \int f\,dm_i$$
for every $f \in C(\Sigma_d)$. More generally, if $\mathbb{P}$ is a Borel probability measure on the compact metrisable space $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$, then defining
$$\int f\,d\mu:=\iint f \,dm\,d\mathbb{P}(m)$$
defines a measure $\mu$ on $\Sigma_d$, which we abbreviate to $\mu=\int m\,d\mathbb{P}(m)$.

Now, it is easy to check that the set of Bernoulli measures is closed in the weak-* topology: one uses the fact that a measure is $(p_1,\ldots,p_d)$-Bernoulli if and only if every cylinder set satisfies an equation in the weights,
$$\mu([x_1\cdots x_n])=p_{x_1}\cdots p_{x_n},$$
and $\mu([x_1\cdots x_n])$ is just $\int \chi \,d\mu$ where $\chi$ is the (continuous) indicator function of the (clopen) cylinder set $[x_1\cdots x_n]$. The set $C$ is thus the set of all measures of the form $\int m\,d\mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is an atomic probability measure supported on the closed set $B$. Since $B$ is closed, the closure of $C$ is the set of all measures of the form $\int m\,d\mathbb{P}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is an arbitrary Borel probability measure on $B$.

I am not quite sure how to answer the question "How big is the closure of $C$?" but I can at least say that it is an infinite-dimensional sub-simplex of $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$, and its only ergodic elements are Bernoulli measures.

Comment: thanks a lot. I really appreciate this part: its only ergodic elements are Bernoulli measures. Good answer. I will try to understand it properly, thanks –

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is good to note that a similar question:
*What is the weak-$^*$ closure of the set*
$$
D=\{\mu\in\mathcal{M}_\sigma: \mu\text{ is isomorphic to some }\nu\in C\}?
$$
has a dramatically different answer: **$D$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}_\sigma$**. This is a corollary to a result of Jean-Paul Thouvenot and Benjy Weiss (still unpublished as far as I know). Weiss announced it during a talk in Prague last year and mentioned that Dan Rudolph also knew that.